# VueJS Using @click on <option> elements and @change on <select> element

Tags: vue.js, onclick, onchange

I have a simple function that manipulates a data between true and false. I use it to make my div hidden and visible like a toggle. I also have a  with three  element. I found out that I cannot use `@click` for `<option>` elements, I need to use `@change` for my `<select>`.

But in this way, whenever an  is selected, the function is being triggered and my data toggles between true and false. Here is my `<select>` element;

```
       <select @change="isDisabled">
          <option>Please select a security type</option>
          <option>No Security</option>
          <option>Personal</option>
          <option>Enterprise</option>
       </select>
```

IsDisabled function takes a variable and change its values between true and false so my div becomes hidden and visible as follows;

```
<div v-if="noSecurity">something</div>
```

But here is the thing, I only want to trigger the function when the user select the "No Security" option. Now it's being triggered whenever I select an option, so it turned out to be some kind of a toggle. But I want to hide the div when I select the "No Security" option and show the div if something different is selected. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for the additional `noSecurity` variable.  Create your select with `v-model` to track the selected value.  Give each option a `value` attribute.

```html
<select v-model="selected">
  <option value="">Please select a security type</option>
  <option value="none">No Security</option>
  <option value="personal">Personal</option>
  <option value="enterprise">Enterprise</option>
</select>
```

Check that value:

```html
<div v-if="selected === 'none'">something</div>
```

You can still use the `noSecurity` check if you prefer by creating a computed:

```js
computed: {
  noSecurity() {
    return this.selected === 'none';
  }
}
```

Here's a demo showing both:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
        selected: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    noSecurity() {
      return this.selected === 'none';
    }
  },
  methods: {},
  created() {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option value="">Please select a security type</option>
    <option value="none">No Security</option>
    <option value="personal">Personal</option>
    <option value="enterprise">Enterprise</option>
  </select>

  <div v-if="selected === 'none'">something</div>
  <div v-if="noSecurity">something</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I've made a CodeSandbox where you could see the result :

https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-meitner-63eno?file=/src/App.vue

But here is the explanation:

```
<template>
  <section>
    <select @change="isDisabled">
      <option>Please select a security type</option>
      <option>No Security</option>
      <option>Personal</option>
      <option>Enterprise</option>
    </select>
    <div v-if="noSecurity">You Choose no security, that's dangerous !</div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      noSecurity: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    isDisabled(e) {
      console.log("e", e.target.value);
       if (e.target.value === "No Security") {
        // do your change
        return (this.noSecurity = !this.noSecurity);
      }
     // to allow reset if another option is selected
      if (this.noSecurity) {
        return this.noSecurity = false;
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Basically when you use the `@change` handler, your function will receive an event, in this event you can catch the target value with `event.target.value`.

Doing so, you do a condition if the value is equal to *No Security* (so the selected item), you change your state, if it's not *No Security*, you do nothing, or you do something else you would like to do.

Appart from that, I advice you to change your method name `isDisabled` to a global convention name like `handleChange`, or `onChange`.

Pass id values in your option so when you get the select event you're clear that *No security* or whatver the name you would like to change will be the same.

Because if one day you change *No security* to another name, you have to update all your conditions in your app. **Try to avoid conditions with strings values** like this if you can.

```
<option value="1">No Security</option> // :value="securityType.Id" for example if coming from your database
<option value="2">Personal</option>
<option value="3">Enterprise</option>
```

then in your function it will be

```
if (e.target.value === noSecurityId) {
 // do your change
 this.noSecurity = !this.noSecurity;
}
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

Is using v-model instead of using a method is option for you? If it is, please try the following:

HTML:

```
<div id="hello-vue" class="demo">
  <select v-model="security">
    <option>Please select a security type</option>
    <option>No Security</option>
    <option>Personal</option>
    <option>Enterprise</option>
  </select>
  <div v-if="security=='No Security'">something</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
const HelloVueApp = {
  data() {
    return {
      security: undefined
    }
  }
}
```